# How to get the onclick event

Tags: ios

code :

```
NSURLRequest *_request =  [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.fx-func.com/h5/lp/16484/1322570745"]];
[myWebView loadRequest:_request];
 <div class="more"><a data-action="fullArticle" href="javascript:;" onclick="function:
 {'action':'edit', 'id': 222, 'info': '2344543534'}">words</a></div>
 </div>
```

I want

```
"function: {'action':'edit', 'id': 222, 'info': '2344543534'}"
```

Comment: <div class="more"><a data-action="fullArticle" href="javascript:;" onclick="function:
 {'action':'edit', 'id': 222, 'info': '2344543534'}">words</a></div>
 </div>\n from webView

Comment: webview load a Request .I would like to interact the html

Comment: U can run javascript code from objective-c like this
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];

and u can write a code to deal with html from the java script code u'll write

Comment: I can get "function"  use  "NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];"  but when the user clicks on "words" interact the html is Difficult。

Comment: User clicks interaction, without clicking does not interact

Comment: Problem solved use “WebViewJavascriptBridge”